# @Value annotation for reading Map from property file

Tags: spring, annotations

My Java has this

```
@Value("#{${validators}}")
private Map<String,String> validators;
```

property file has this

```
validators={AlphabetValidator:'AlphabetValidator',NumberValidator:'NumberValidator'AlphaNumericValidator:'AlphaNumericValidator',DateValidator:'DateValidator', FixedLengthValidator:'FixedLengthValidator',MinimumLengthValidator:'MinimumLengthValidator',MaximumLengthValidator:'MaximumLengthValidator',CustomValidator:'CustomValidator' MandatoryFieldValidator: 'MandatoryFieldValidator',TimeValidator:'TimeValidator'}
```

when I run the app..  I am getting this error

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'validatorProperties': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'validators'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression
>   parsing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E:(pos
>   1): After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the
>   expression: 'lcurly({)'

Answer (score 1):

Check out for comma ',' in property file.

**Properties file:**

```
validators={AlphabetValidator:'AlphabetValidator',NumberValidator:'NumberValidator',AlphaNumericValidator:'AlphaNumericValidator',DateValidator:'DateValidator',FixedLengthValidator:'FixedLengthValidator',MinimumLengthValidator:'MinimumLengthValidator',MaximumLengthValidator:'MaximumLengthValidator',CustomValidator:'CustomValidator',MandatoryFieldValidator:'MandatoryFieldValidator',TimeValidator:'TimeValidator'}
```

**Java code:**

```
@Value("#{${validators}}")
private Map<String,String> validators;
```

Comment: In your example, is it possible to have a space character in key/value, if yes so? Trying:
`validators={Alphabet Validator:'AlphabetValidator'` or `validators={AlphabetValidator:'Alphabet Validator'` doesn't work, result is parse exception.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to specify some commas inside your properties. Try with following:

```
validators={AlphabetValidator:'AlphabetValidator',NumberValidator:'NumberValidator',AlphaNumericValidator:'AlphaNumericValidator',DateValidator:'DateValidator',FixedLengthValidator:'FixedLengthValidator',MinimumLengthValidator:'MinimumLengthValidator',MaximumLengthValidator:'MaximumLengthValidator',CustomValidator:'CustomValidator',MandatoryFieldValidator:'MandatoryFieldValidator',TimeValidator:'TimeValidator'}
```